# Repair corrupted hdf5 file

Tags: hdf5

We are saving time of flight mass spectra in hdf5 files. For more than 99% of the cases this works without any errors. But sometimes measurements crashes.

We save different (meta-) data but my question is about one incrementing table:

- Storage Layout: CHUNKED: 1x1x10x248584
- Compression: 8,312:1GZIP: level=5

Values are inserted each time step (usually 10 seconds). After 1min the layout is 6x1x10x248584.

But the corrupted table has size: 0x1x10x248584 (Tried with h5py 2.10.0 and HDFView 3.1.0).

My question: Is there any low-level library (python preferred) where I can try to access the lost data? The file size (measuring several hours --> several GB) promises the data is there, but cannot be read with those two programs I tried.
Thank you.

[Update]:
In HDFView it looks like this for the corrupted File. From file size I expect the first dimension to be >1000.
[image]

Comment: You can use the h5py library to open the files. You could use an assertion on shape as a basic check without reading the data. A question to you is: how did the data get corrupted. I have had the same problem before when I used the C++ API. Since I switch to the C API (with a different C++ wrapper) I have not experienced the problem of corruption once.

Comment: This (f['path_to_array'].shape) returns the same values (0x1x10x248584).
Changes on the side of data creation are impossible for us (by now), because its a closed source software :-(

Comment: If I open with read/write h5py.File('name.h5', 'r+') the file size shrinks to ~1mb (before 2gb), which means that h5py then only stores the data which it found by reading it.

Comment: I presume that you loop over all datasets and try to read and otherwise skip?

Comment: No, I know which dataset I want and can address it directly ( h5py.File('fname.h5')['FullSpectra/TofData'] ).